# Set transparent fill for box plots using px.box

Tags: python, plotly, transparency, boxplot, plotly.graph-objects

```
import plotly.express as px
bar = px.box([1,2,3,4], color_discrete_sequence=["rgb(50,50,50)"])
bar
```

How to set transparency of the box fill directly in using px.box? I'm aware of this answer using graphobjects but I sould like to do it directly using px.
Thanks